# Average the same model over multiple runs or take an ensamble of a multitude of the same model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras

Currently I'm averaging predictions using the same model, I re-initialize the model and fit to a different test set of data from the same data sample, then I average over all of the prediction accuracies

Seems there are multiple possible ways to do this.

1. Average together the predictions such as in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/478794/should-i-run-a-machine-learning-model-many-times).
2. Average all the final model weights together such as [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/109990/how-to-compute-the-mean-of-weights-of-multiple-models).
3. I could find an average ensamble (but using the same model for all of the input models), or go a step further and make it a [weighted average ensamble](https://machinelearningmastery.com/weighted-average-ensemble-with-python/).
4. I could [stack ensambles](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacking-ensemble-machine-learning-with-python/) to create a model that learns which models are the best predictors.

While 1 and 2 deal with the same type of model e.g. keras models, in 3 and 4 I can use multiple different models. But is it a good approach to use 3 and 4 instead of 1 and 2 by just making all the models in the ensamble the same (though acting on different training sets). Furthermore, the ensamble approach allows for different types of models. It seems that 3 and 4 could be used instead of 1 or 2 as they are more general? That is, for example, using 3, finding a weighted average of N copies of the same model? If so, would stacking ensambles (in 4) be better than just weighting them (in 3), that is, creating a higher level model to learn which of the lower level models make better predictions?

Comment: I lost a lung reading this question... this is supposed to be A question, not SOME questions.  Please clarify which is the actual question (and which are just thoughts with a question mark)

Comment: Ok. Hopefully it is more clear. Thanks.